# Isolate LAN network

Tags: networking, home-networking

My home network consists of 4 computers connected with wifi. Problem is the people who own 2 of the computers don't really know how to protect against viruses. Is there a way to either create 2 ceperate lan or block LAN connection to some of the computers.

Comment: Don't worry. Virus will most likely only effect the local computer and won't spread to others. Just make sure you fine tune your security settings on Windows and you'll be fine.

Comment: @t.thielemans hmmm maybe if I block 192.168.2.2-254 on my computer

Comment: Just set your security settings in Windows, that's more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot share @t.thielemans' optimism, some malware does search for neighbours.

Do you control the router? If so, you should set up a VLAN, some routers let you do that. This would be the cleanest solution, even though perhaps it may prove insufficient: if the malware leaves a backdoor, a skilled malicious user may log onto the infected pc, and from there try to infiltrate the router. So hardening the LAN side of the router is also in order.

You may completely block, with your firewall, access from the other pcs. Actually, you may even block access from `any` pc inside your network, except for the router.

Or, and this is in my mind the best solution, you may reason with this people and make them understand the need for some form of prevention.

You should keep in mind the unwanted consequences of not guarding against malware. Any mischief perpetrated by someone through one of the pcs in your LAN can be traced back to your IP address, and you may suffer unwanted and unforeseen consequences, like being inserted in blacklists, investigated for crimes, attacked or investigated by anyone the hacker may have annoyed when working off your LAN, and so on.

There is also the unpleasant thought that your network may (unwillingly) host a porn-site (you did not really think they would keep this stuff on their own sites, did you?), especially those of a particularly unsavory nature.

Comment: Yes I do control the router. I'm thinking of blocking everything with the firewall tho I'm not completely sure if I need to block the broadcast address.

Comment: @Fanj No, do not block the broadcast address: the router uses it to identify pcs, and it needs to contact yours too to confirm the association between MAC number and IP address, a key part of networking.